# Two similar implementations quit dramatic difference times to run

Tags: python, numpy, runtime

I've tried the basic cython tutorial [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) to see how significant the speed up is. 
I've also made two different python implementations which differ quit significantly in runtime. I've tested run times of the differences, and as far as I can see, they do not explain the overall runtime difference.

The code is calculating the first kmax primes:

```
def pyprimes1(kmax):
    p=[]
    result = []
    if kmax > 1000:
        kmax = 1000
    k = 0
    n = 2
    while k < kmax:
        i = 0
        while i < k and n % p[i] != 0:
            i = i + 1
        if i == k:
            p.append(n)
            k = k + 1
            result.append(n)
        n = n + 1
    return result

def pyprimes2(kmax):
    p=zeros(kmax)
    result = []
    if kmax > 1000:
        kmax = 1000
    p=zeros(kmax)
    k = 0
    n = 2
    while k < kmax:
        i = 0
        while i < k and n % p[i] != 0:
            i = i + 1
        if i == k:
            p[k] = n
            k = k + 1
            result.append(n)
        n = n + 1
    return result
```

As you can see, the only difference between the two implementations is in the usage of the `p` variable, in the first it is a python list, in the other it is a numpy array. I used IPython %timeit magic to test timinigs. who do you think preformed better? here is what I got:

```
%timeit pyprimes1(1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 79.4 ms per loop

%timeit pyprimes2(1000)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.14 s per loop
```

That was strange and surprising, as I thought a numpy array pre-allocated and probably C implemented would be much faster.

I've also test:
array assignment:

```
%timeit p[100]=5
10000000 loops, best of 3: 116 ns per loop
```

array selection:

```
%timeit p[100]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 252 ns per loop
```

which was twice slower.. also didnt expect that. 
array initialization:

```
%timeit zeros(1000)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 µs per loop
```

list appending:

```
%timeit p.append(1)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 164 ns per loop
```

list selection:

```
%timeit p[100]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 56 ns per loop
```

So it seems list selection is 5 times faster then array selection. 
I cant see how this numbers adds-up to the more then x10 time difference. while we do selection in each iteration, it is only 5 times faster.

Would appriciate an explanation regarding the timing differnces bewtween arrays and lists and also the overall time differnce between the two implementations. or am I using %timeit wrong by measuring time on increased length list?

BTW, the cython code did best at 3.5ms.

Comment: Why do you set `zeros` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1000th prime number is 7919. So if on average the inner loops iterates kmax/2 times (very roughly), your program performs approx. 7919 * (1000/2) ~ = 4*10<sup>6</sup> selections from the array/list. If a single selection from a list for the first version takes 56 ns, even the selections wouldn't fit into 79 ms (0.056 µs * 4*10<sup>6</sup> ~ = 0.22 sec).

Probably these nanosecond times are not very accurate.

By the way, performance of `append` depends on size of the list. In some cases it can lead to reallocation, but in most the list has enough free space and it's lightning fast.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy's main use case is to perform operations on whole arrays and slices, not single elements. Those operations are implemented in C and therefore much faster than the equivalent Python code. For example,

```
c = a + b
```

will be much faster than

```
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
```

even if the variables are `numpy` arrays in both cases.

However, single element operations like the ones you are testing may well be worse than Python lists. Python lists are plain C arrays of structs, which are quite simple to access.

On the other hand, accessing an element in a `numpy` array comes with lots of overhead to support multiple raw data formats and advanced indexing options, among other reasons.